# understanding jupyter notebook interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am beginning to learn python. My background in programming languages is with MatLab and Mathematica; I'm a math person with zero knowledge in computer science.

However, my currently most difficult hurdle is trying to figure the "big picture" as to the interface of jupyter notebook.

I have an anaconda navigator installed which includes packages like Rstudio, jupyterlab and glueviz. I run either one of these packages via the anaconda navigator.

In attempting some tutorials, I am asked to run a csv file via `import pandas as pd`.

Upon googling, panda appears to be a package.

1) I am unsure if it has already been installed. How do I check if it has been installed.

2) If it hasn't been installed, how do I install it? I have tried pasting the command line `conda install -c conda-forge pandas` on the mac terminal but nothing happens.

Help would be appreciated. Feel free to explain as though I'm an idiot.

Comment: The Anaconda distribution ships with a bunch of data science packages which INCLUDES pandas, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn and a bunch of other packages

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan are they installed by default? How does one determine if they are installed?

Comment: Just try with this line: `import pandas as pd` if it gives an error it is not installed

Comment: 1).Type `conda list` in the command line to see the existing packages. 2).To install a new package, refer the documentation of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('yourData.csv')
print(data)
```

put your csv file  where you made this jupyter ipython file to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you for the contribution.
Could you also provide a tangential suggestion as to how to change the path directory that python is currently searching for the file?

Comment: if you mean changing jupyter default path, you can refere to this post:
https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/LcaXE25qElM

Comment: but the easiest way is to move your csv file to the directory anaconda uses

Comment: Is there a way for me to determine the search directory anaconda uses?

Comment: In windows, the default path is C:\Users\your_user\
in  mac it should be something similar